# Kotlin how to return a SINGLE object from a list that contains a specific id?

Tags: android, kotlin

Good day, i'm stuck figuring out how to get a single object from a list, i did google but all the topics show how to return a `List` with sorted objects or something similar.

I have a `User Class`

```
class User() {

    var email: String = ""
    var firstname:  String = ""
    var lastname: String  = ""
    var password: String  = ""
    var image: String  = ""
    var userId: String  = ""

    constructor(email:String,
                firstname: String,
                lastname: String,
                password: String,
                image: String, userId : String) : this() {
        this.email = email
        this.firstname = firstname
        this.lastname = lastname
        this.password = password
        this.image = image
        this.userId = userId
    }
}
```

In java i would write something like

```
 User getUserById(String id) {
        User user = null;
        for(int i = 0; i < myList.size;i++;) {
            if(id == myList.get(i).getUserId())
            user = myList.get(i)
        }
        return user;
    }
```

How can i achieve the same result in kotlin?

Answer (score 92):

You can do this with [`find`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/find.html), which gives you the first element of a list that matches a given predicate (or `null`, if none matched):

```
val user: User? = myList.find { it.userId == id }
```

Or if you really do need the last element that matches the predicate, as your Java example code does, you can use [`last`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/last.html):

```
val user: User? = myList.last { it.userId == id }
```

Comment: You can also use first extension function, But it can throw exception if your searched item not exist

Answer (score 21):

Simplify

```
val user: User = myList.single { it.userId == id }
```

or if may list not have your filter

```
val user: User? = myList.singleOrNull{ it.userId == id }
```

Answer (score 17):

If you don't want to deal with null objects, try this:

```
val index = myList.indexOfFirst { it.userId == id } // -1 if not found
if (index >= 0) {  
    val user = myList[index]
    // do something with user
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this extension function also which return pair Pair(Boolean,T)

e.g

```
val id=2
val item= myList.customContains{it-> it.userId ==id}

if(item.first){
item.second  //your object
//    your code here
}else{
// if item no present
}




fun <E> List<E>.customContains(function: (currentItem: E) -> Boolean): Pair<Boolean, E?> {
        for (current in 0 until this.size) {
            if (function(this[current])) {
                return Pair(true, this[current])
            }
        }
        return Pair(false, null)
    }
```